# react component css space aligning on elements not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I was playing around with glass morphism - I have following two files:
CharacterFormComp.js and
CharacterFormView.js

CharacterForm.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./CharacterForm.css";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class CharacterFormComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super()
    }

    render() {
        const data = this.props.data;
        return(
            <div className="character-form-component">
                { 
                    typeof(data) !== 'undefined' ? (
                        data.map(e => {
                            return (
                                <div className="segment">
                                    <label>{e}</label>
                                    <input id={e}/>
                            
                                </div>
                            );
                        })
                    ):("none")
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

CharacterFormComp.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.array
}

export default CharacterFormComp;
```

CharacterFormView.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar";
import CharacterFormComp from "./CharacterFormComp";


class CharacterFormView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        const testData = ["1", "2"]
        return(
            <div>
                <Navbar/>
                <div style={{overflow: "auto"}}>
                <CharacterFormComp data={testData}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CharacterFormView;
```

Nothing complex like you see.

The object "1" and "2" are rendering like it is programmed in CharacterFormComp.js.
But however they are overlaying each other.
Usually they should appear with a simple space like a list of inputs with labels.
Like you see I also have imported a css file which should do the space with:

```
.segment {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 40%;
    width: 20vw;
    margin: 3%;
}
```

I'm sure the css import is working because it looks like the glass morphism element but this spacing with `margin: 5%;` between the two label + inputs does not work
Does anyone know why they are overlapping instead of being separated with a space?
How can I fix this?

if you need the whole css I can share of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend changing the CSS to:

```css
.segment {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  left: 40%;
  width: 20vw;
  margin: 3%;
}
```

I'll leave a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sea-4l56h?file=/src/components/CharacterForm.css:0-145) to a sandbox to let you see the results.